# How do I enable 2160x1440 resolution on Ubuntu 21.10 on VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, display-resolution, xrandr, guest-additions

I am running Ubuntu 21.10 on VirtualBox on a Huawei Matebook 14 2021.  The native screen resolution of the laptop is 2160x1440.  I have also tried Ubuntu 20.04 with the same results.

I've tried to add the resolution with `xrandr`, but when I load it, the screen turns black:

```
xrandr -s 2160x1440
```

How do I enable 2160x1440 resolution?

Comment: Is that screen resolution not available as an option in Display System Settings?  Tell us more about the hardware. Is there a dedicated GPU or only an iGPU? What model GPU and CPU?

Comment: i've got a i7 11th with an iris xe  and ubuntu is running on virtual box. After adding the res with xrandr the res is available in the display settings but when I select it it goes black

Comment: It's definitely important to know that you're running Ubuntu in VirtualBox.  Operating systems in VirtualBox are not actually running on your hardware.  You need to install [Guest Additions](https://askubuntu.com/q/22743)